# Трабл вложенных RelativeLayout's

Tags: android, java

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?
Есть такая разметка

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <!-- top bar -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar_bg" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/diafilm_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Test Test"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_butt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/share_selector" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bookmarks_butt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bookmark_selector" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sett_butt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/settings_selector" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/divider" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev_butt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/prev_selector" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/play_butt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/play_selector" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_butt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/next_selector" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- content -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_bar"
        android:layout_margin="2dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" >

            <ru.diafilm.CustomGallery
                android:id="@+id/screen_img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#060405"
                android:spacing="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/background" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/invisible_view"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slides_bar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/slides_text"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/slides_grid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:columnWidth="90dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="1"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Проблема в том, что не смотря на заданный атрибут в нижнем лэйауте android:layout_below="[[@id](/users/3123/idanil)](/users/3123/idanil)/top_bar", верхний лэйаут занимает весь экран.

Comment: Попробуйте с весами поиграть у top_bar'а и content'а

Comment: В RelativeLayout вес не работает

Comment: так корневой можно LinearLayout поставить

Comment: От этого ничего не изменится. Должно работать без весов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не рекомендуется вкладывать друг в друга `RelativeLayout` и вообще вкладывать внутрь `RelativeLayout` что либо ибо как говорит документация:

> A RelativeLayout is a very powerful
> utility for designing a user interface
> because it can eliminate nested
> ViewGroups. If you find yourself using
> several nested LinearLayout groups,
> you may be able to replace them with a
> single RelativeLayout.

По русски это означает, что у вас трабл с дизайном страницы - поскольку `RelativeLayout` как раз инструмент для удаления вложенности `ViewGroup`.

Удалите фсенафик и покурите/попейте кофейке и напишите свой лэйаут заново.

Comment: Здорово конечно, но нет четкого ограничения на создание подобной страницы. Приму к сведению совет, спасибо.

Comment: Убери для начала вложение Relative в Relative - это точно абсолютно лишнее

Comment: Есть идея как сверстать данную страницу, чтобы верхний топбар и контент находились в RelativeLayout каждый? Это нужно для того, чтобы на разных разрешениях макет оставался таким же неизменным, а точнее неизменными графические элементы и их положение. Поставил кнопку справа с бэкграундом, она будет справа на любом разрешении с тем же бэкграундом. При использовании весов(пропорций) графические элементы будут растягиваться.